# Get YouTube video id from url in a custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, youtube, html5, video-player

Here's the scenario, I have a site with thousands of YouTube video posts which are stored in a custom field 'video_url' which is being used in a custom video player.

The custom player I'm using now doesn't take the entire YouTube URL but instead just the video ID. What I need to do is figure out how to grab the YouTube video ID from the url in the custom field and place that into a HTML 5 video attribute.

```
<video class="custom-player" data-youtube-id="YOUTUBE_ID_HERE" width="700" height="420" preload="none"></video>
```

Thanks.

### Update: Answer

Credits to Chandan Chaudhary https://gist.github.com/ckchaudhary/8629242#file-get-youtube-video-id-from-url

Add the following to the functions.php file.

```
function extractUTubeVidId($url){
    /*
    * type1: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jr6OtgiOIw
    * type2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jr6OtgiOIw&feature=related
    * type3: http://youtu.be/9Jr6OtgiOIw
    */
    $vid_id = "";
    $flag = false;
    if(isset($url) && !empty($url)){
        /*case1 and 2*/
        $parts = explode("?", $url);
        if(isset($parts) && !empty($parts) && is_array($parts) && count($parts)>1){
            $params = explode("&", $parts[1]);
            if(isset($params) && !empty($params) && is_array($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $kv = explode("=", $param);
                    if(isset($kv) && !empty($kv) && is_array($kv) && count($kv)>1){
                        if($kv[0]=='v'){
                            $vid_id = $kv[1];
                            $flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*case 3*/
        if(!$flag){
            $needle = "youtu.be/";
            $pos = null;
            $pos = strpos($url, $needle);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $start = $pos + strlen($needle);
                $vid_id = substr($url, $start, 11);
                $flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $vid_id;
}
```

The add this to the post loop.

```
<?php 
$videoID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', true); 
echo $youtube_video_id = extractUTubeVidId($videoID);   
?>
```

Change 'video_url' to whatever custom field name your YouTube video URLs are stored in.

Comment: Do you know how to get the URL and you're just asking how to split it?

Comment: I figured it out, I updated my question.

Comment: Submit your solution as an answer and mark it solved so that the question does not go listed as unanswered. Also, fwiw, you probably want to look at PHP's [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) as it may lend itself to a slightly better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credits to Chandan Chaudhary https://gist.github.com/ckchaudhary/8629242#file-get-youtube-video-id-from-url

Add the following to the functions.php file.

```
function extractUTubeVidId($url){
    /*
    * type1: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jr6OtgiOIw
    * type2: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Jr6OtgiOIw&feature=related
    * type3: http://youtu.be/9Jr6OtgiOIw
    */
    $vid_id = "";
    $flag = false;
    if(isset($url) && !empty($url)){
        /*case1 and 2*/
        $parts = explode("?", $url);
        if(isset($parts) && !empty($parts) && is_array($parts) && count($parts)>1){
            $params = explode("&", $parts[1]);
            if(isset($params) && !empty($params) && is_array($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $kv = explode("=", $param);
                    if(isset($kv) && !empty($kv) && is_array($kv) && count($kv)>1){
                        if($kv[0]=='v'){
                            $vid_id = $kv[1];
                            $flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /*case 3*/
        if(!$flag){
            $needle = "youtu.be/";
            $pos = null;
            $pos = strpos($url, $needle);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $start = $pos + strlen($needle);
                $vid_id = substr($url, $start, 11);
                $flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return $vid_id;
}
```

The add this to the post loop.

```
<?php 
$videoID = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_url', true); 
echo $youtube_video_id = extractUTubeVidId($videoID);   
?>
```

Change 'video_url' to whatever custom field name your YouTube video URLs are stored in.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to use WordPress's build in auto embed, the following line in core is responsible for auto embed:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array(&$this, 'autoembed'), 8 );
```

Which means: Whenever we are about to display content try to auto embed all url's with a priority of 8.

You could add a custom filter before this one to add the youtube url's, like so:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_add_youtube_videos', 7 );
function prefix_add_youtube_videos( $content ) {
    $video = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true );
    if ( ! empty( $video ) ) {
        $content .= $video;
    }

    return $content;
}
```

So we add our function with priority 7 so it's before WordPress's auto embed and so WordPress will embed the video for us. That is less code you'll have to maintain.

PS Embedding is good! Don't [freeboot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6A1Lt0kvMA)!

Comment: But how would that work in a custom video player.

Comment: It doesn't work with a custom video player, I'm just giving an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any, even basic experience with PHP, this can be rather straight forward to setup.

Have a look at [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr).

```
<?php

  // explode() will split the string up into an array, for ex:
  $youtube_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
  $youtube_array = explode('?v=', $youtube_url);

  // we used '?v=' as the delimter, so explode will create an array of two parts, the first being everything before the delimiter and the second being everything after (the YouTube ID)

        print_r($youtube_array);
        // will print: Array ( [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch [1] => dQw4w9WgXcQ )

        echo $youtube_array[1];
        // will echo: dQw4w9WgXcQ
?>
```

If all your inputed YouTube links follow the exact same format (for ex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) then our work here is done. But, we all know that YouTube links come in all shapes and sizes with extra variables attached.

```
<?php

  // lets use a more complicated link
  $youtube_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ&list=RDdQw4w9WgXcQ#t=0';
  $youtube_array = explode('?v=', $youtube_url);

        print_r($youtube_array);
        // will print: Array ( [0] => https://www.youtube.com/watch [1] => dQw4w9WgXcQ&list=RDdQw4w9WgXcQ#t=0 )

        echo $youtube_array[1];
        // will echo: dQw4w9WgXcQ&list=RDdQw4w9WgXcQ#t=0

        // we can use substr() to pull out just the id by cuting it down to the first 11 characters of the string, all YouTube IDs are 11 characters
        $youtube_id = substr($youtube_array[1], 0, 11);

        echo $youtube_id;
        // will echo: dQw4w9WgXcQ
?>
```

Of course, some YouTube links can also follow this format: `http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ`. Which would use a different delimiter `.be/` and you could write a function to check for both. Please let us know your PHP experience level. And check to see how all your links are formatted. And have a look at those two functions above.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I'm a PHP beginner.

Comment: I don't mean to sound condescending, but even so, you could probably figure this out from my examples. I'm no super PHP user either, and `explode` was one of the first functions I ever learned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this directly in a template or with some type of action or filter hook

```
wp_oembed_get( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_url', true ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

I use a regular expression to match and return a youtube video id from a url:

```
<?php    
  /**
   * Match non-linked youtube URL in the wild.
   * : Regex Overview/Pseudo-code :
   * 
   * Required scheme. Either http or https.
   * Optional subdomain.
   * Group host alternatives.
   * Either youtu.be
   * or youtube.com 
   * or youtube-nocookie.com
   * followed by
   * Allow anything up to VIDEO_ID,
   * but char before ID is non-ID char.
   * End host alternatives.
   * $1: VIDEO_ID is exactly 11 chars.
   * Assert next char is non-ID or EOS.
   * Assert URL is not pre-linked.
   * Allow URL (query) remainder.
   * Group pre-linked alternatives.
   * Either inside a start tag,
   * or inside <a> element text contents.
   * End recognized pre-linked alts.
   * End negative lookahead assertion.
   * Consume any URL (query) remainder.
   */

function getYoutubeVideoID ( $youtube_url ) {

  return preg_replace('~https?://(?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)?(?:youtu\.be/| youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com\S*[^\w\s-])([\w-]{11})(?=[^\w-]|$)(?![?=&+%\w.-]*(?:[\'"][^<>]*>| </a>))[?=&+%\w.-]*~ix', '$1', $youtube_url);

}
```

Call function by providing youtube url, like so:

```
// example urls
$this_video_url = 'https://youtu.be/RVWtSsMUBD0';
$this_video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVWtSsMUBD0';

$this_youtube_id = getYoutubeVideoID( $this_video_url );
echo 'YouTube ID: ' . $this_youtube_id;
```

Comment: I think you messed the regex comments up. They belong into the regex behind a `#`.

Comment: @toscho I'm not sure I've messed anything up. I'm able to copy+paste and run this code. Would you mind elaborating? Thanks :-)

Comment: The modifier `x` says that you can embed comments in the regex to explain each part better. Putting these comments on top is rather confusing. See http://wpkrauts.com/2013/enforce-utf-8-with-php/ for an example.